# Hyperlink button in all pages

Tags: beamer, hyperref

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to edit Beamer theme CambridgeUS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66925/how-to-edit-beamer-theme-cambridgeus)

How do I put the same hyperlink button (that opens a pdf file `list.pdf`) in all slides at same position (header bar or footline ) in the beamer presentation while using `cambridgeUS` theme?

The preamble looks like this

```
%\usecolortheme[named=Brown]{structure}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=red!65!black, fg=white}
%% Macro for inserting Page number in Warsaw theme
%\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
%\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
%\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
%  \oldmacro\hfill%
%  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\usepackage{ragged2e}\title{Lecture 003}
\author[The Author]{The Author}
\institute[IIT Madras]{Assistant Professor \\Department of Electrical    Engineering\\Indian Institute of Technology Madras}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=1cm]{iitmlogo}{/home/melvinp/Dropbox/NPTEL/Lecture2/IITMLogo.pdf}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{iitmlogo}}

\date{}

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}}

%\AtBeginSubsection[]
%{
%  \begin{frame}<beamer>
%    \frametitle{Layout}
%    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
%  \end{frame}
%}
\justifying{
```

I'm new to LyX and I don't know LaTeX.

I'm using `beamer` document class and have around 1500 slides of presentation, which is too big. So I split it into 15 files with 100 slides each as `Lecture1.lyx + Lecture1.pdf`, `Lecture2.lyx + Lecture2.pdf` etc. I've developed `list.lyx and list.pdf` with of all the sections,subsection, and subsubsections (in `article` document class). When I click on one of the topic in `list.pdf` the corresponding `lecture##.pdf` opens because I have hyperlinked them.

But, I want a button in all my 1500 slides, that when I click it, the `list.pdf` must open (what is the code that i can put in the preamble for this?).

In some cases, when I click on a `subsubsection` it should open the corresponding PDF file and go to the exact slide where the data is present.

If these are possible then the next problem is that so many PDF files get opened after going through for some time. So, when I click a hyperlink "abc" in `list.pdf`, the `list.pdf` should close and the corresponding PDF file opens and points to the required slide. Similarly, when I click the button on any of the 1500 slides, the file that contains the button should close and the `list.pdf` should open. So, at a time I have only one PDF file open.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer your question without more details on what you want, but you could easily add a hyperlink on the header bar or the footline, for example by doing:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.2em,wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=0.5cm,rightskip=0.5cm]{footlinecolor}
    \hspace{0.3cm}%
   \insertshortauthor{}  \hfill \insertshorttitle \hfill Slide \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber \hfill \url{http://www.example.com}

  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

Comment: I tried these codes, it worked but I have to use \usetheme{CambridgeUS}, which has author, title and page number, Is it possible to add the hyperlink as the fourth ? instead of having only the hyperlink.

Comment: @MelvinPaul: I think it is better if you edit your initial question by adding these further details (theme used, the position where to insert the button). They really help in writing a more suitable answer.