# How to edit Beamer theme CambridgeUS

Tags: beamer, hyperref, header-footer, themes

I have been using the beamer document class with the theme- cambridgeUS in lyx. The following code is the preamble. Now, I want to insert a hyperlink to a pdf file in all the pages by adding them in the header or the footer. The footer at present has the author, title and page number. How do I add the fourth? Or how can it be done with the header?

```
%\usecolortheme[named=Brown]{structure}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=red!65!black, fg=white}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%% Macro for inserting Page number in Warsaw theme
%\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
%\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
%\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
%  \oldmacro\hfill%
%  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\usepackage{ragged2e}\title{TE TM Hybrid Modes}
\author[Dr. James]{Dr. James}
\institute[IIT Madras]{ \\Department of Electrical Engineering\\Indian Institute of Technology Madras}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=1cm]{iitmlogo}{/home/melvinp/Dropbox/NPTEL/Lecture2/IITMLogo.pdf}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{iitmlogo}}

\date{}

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}}

%\AtBeginSubsection[]
%{
%  \begin{frame}<beamer>
 %   \frametitle{Layout}
  %  \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
 % \end{frame}
%}
%\justifying{
```

Thank You

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `CambridgeUS` theme uses the outer theme `infolines`. You can download [the original file from CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty) and use it as a basis to make your own outer theme with an external link.

In this example the footer contains a fourth field with a link to the beamer user guide:

```
\mode<presentation>

\setbeamercolor*{author in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary}
\setbeamercolor*{title in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary}
\setbeamercolor*{date in head/foot}{parent=palette primary}

\setbeamercolor*{section in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary}
\setbeamercolor*{subsection in head/foot}{parent=palette primary}
% colors for the external link field
\setbeamercolor*{external link}{parent=palette secondary}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{withlink theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber 
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  % this is a new field with an external link
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{external link}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\href{http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf}{Link to manual}\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{withlink theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=1em,text margin right=1em}

\mode
<all>
```

Save this as `beamerouterthemewithlink.sty` and put it in your project folder or the local tex-mf tree. Then you can use it by adding this line in your tex file:

```
\useoutertheme{withlink}
```

[image: beamerthemewithlink]

Similarly, you could also modify the header by adding another `beamercolorbox`. Just make sure that the total width of all `beamercolorbox`es is equal to `\textwidth`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution that adds a link to a web ressource immediatly above the navigation symbols.  This is done by modifying the `sidebar right` template. (Additions to the footer are also possible, but may be more appropriate for additional titling information.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=red!65!black,fg=white}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}
{
  \vfill%
  \llap{\insertlogo\hskip0.1cm}%
  \vskip2pt%
  \llap{\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{A link to tex.sx}\hskip0.2cm}% NEW
  \vskip3pt% NEW
  \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
  \vskip2pt%
}

\begin{document}

\title{TE TM Hybrid Modes}
\author{Dr. James}
\institute[IIT Madras]{Department of Electrical Engineering\\
     Institute of Technology Madras}
\date{}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing a problem with the beamer class file. I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[slidestop,mathsrif]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{lily}
\beamertemplateballitem
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\title[Many-body Physics with Stationary Light]{\color{red!50!green}{\bf Realization of Strongly Correlated Many-body Physics with Stationary Light}}
\subtitle{}
\author[Priyam Das]{\bf Priyam Das}
\institute{\color{green!60!blue} Institute of Nuclear Physics,\\ Hacettepe University}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

The moment I tried to enter a short institute name through "\institute[short institute]{Detail address}", I get the following error :

```
! Use of \beamer@institute doesn't match its definition.
\inserttitle ->\color {
                       red!50!green}{\bf Realization of Strongly Correlated ...
l.15 \begin{document}
```

If I continue by ignoring the error, I get the following: a repetitive title, but the problem with the short institute at the below does not exist.

[image: Output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This does not provide an answer to the question. If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. You can link back to the original question here if it provides context or motivation for your new question.