# How to add the footnote in the right down corner with the background color(only page)&change time background color

Tags: beamer

My question can be seen as follows

[image: right down corner&background color]

My question is

1. put the footnote in the right down corner and change color to the
   background
2. change time background color(may be solved by the question 1)

My code is  （forgive me by using the 
Werner MWE）

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[timeinterval=1]{tdclock}
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=1.5\baselineskip
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}

\setbeamertemplate{footline} 
{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}


\begin{document}
\title[Title]{My title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute[Institute]{My institute}
\date[\initclock\tdtime]{\today}
\logo{\color{blue!50}\scalebox{2}{\TeX}} % you can % it
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
  Some text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Some more text
\end{frame}

\section{Another section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\begin{frame}
  Some final text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next you will find a partial solution to your problem. I've changed your `footline` definition to

```
\makeatletter
\newdimen\mywidth%
\setlength{\mywidth}{\paperwidth}%
\addtolength{\mywidth}{-\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
\setbeamertemplate{footline} 
{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@sidebarwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{sidebar}%
\end{beamercolorbox}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\mywidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{normal text}%
\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\hfill\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

Now `footline` is constructed with two `beamercolorboxes` the first one is empty is as width as left sidebar. The second one fills slide width and places clock and framenumbers aligned to the right. I don't know how to change clock background color.

[image]

I think a better solution would be to place clock and frame numbers on a phantom right sidebar like navigation symbols, but I don't know how to do it.

EDIT:

From [lockstep's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66932/1952) to [How to edit Beamer theme CambridgeUS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66925/how-to-edit-beamer-theme-cambridgeus/66932#66932) I've learned how to use `sidebar right` to place clock and frame numbers. It's easy, just insert

```
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}
{
  \vfill%
%  \llap{\insertlogo\hskip0.1cm}%
%  \vskip2pt%
  \llap{%
%   \usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip1em%
    \insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}\insertframenumber{} /\inserttotalframenumber
  \hskip0.1cm}%
  \vskip2pt%
}
```

in your preamble and forget `footline` definition. The result will be the same without worries about color backgrounds and sidebar widths. Previous definition avoids printing
`navigation symbols`, if you want to show them, comment out the corresponding line.

Comment: Thanks,I get the solution,but why this is not true


`\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=50pt,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{sidebar}%
\end{beamercolorbox}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth-50pt,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{normal text}%`


the "\paperwidth-50pt"

Comment: @ytyyutianyun I don't know, this was my first test and failed so, I changed to `\addtolength`. I'll look into it, but not now.

Comment: Thank you for your help, And the last question,do you know why the background of the clock is different from others and can I edit it(color)？

Comment: @ytyyutianyun No, I don't. May be you can send a message to its creator(s). Probably you will find it in its manual.

Comment: @ytyyutianyun I've made a [new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140230/1952) about your first comment.

Comment: thank you for your help and the question! That's just what I wanted

Comment: @ytyyutianyun I've found how to use `sidebar right` instead of complicated `footline`.

Comment: Yes, I get the solution solved! 
Thanks, I appreciate your attention