# Why a calc operation in width of beamercolorbox doesn't work?

Tags: beamer, calculations

Trying to answer [How to add the footnote in the right down corner with the background color(only page)&change time background color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139520/how-to-add-the-footnote-in-the-right-down-corner-with-the-background-coloronly/140031#140031) I wanted to calculate  `beamercolorbox` width as `wd=\pagewidth-\beamer@sidebarwidth` but if failed, even with `\usepackage{calc}`. Do you know why?

Next you have an example to test it. First solution (with `calc`) doesn't work, second and third (with `\addtolength` and pgf-calc library) work.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  % wd=5cm-1cm does not work
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=5cm-1cm]{sidebar}
  First box
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \newlength{\mylength}
  \setlength{\mylength}{5cm}
  \addtolength{\mylength}{-1cm}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\mylength]{sidebar}
  First box
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \pgfmathsetmacro{\lengthb}{5-1}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\lengthb cm]{sidebar}
  First box
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `beamer` is pre-`pgfkeys` era. I didn't check it but probably the `wd=` is directly stored in a dimen and there is no possibility to catch the calculation. You might try `\dimexpr...\relax` if luck is on our side it should work :)

Comment: @percusse That's an answer right there.

Comment: @percusse So, this is the normal behaviour. Isn't it? It's is not possible to use calc to set beamercolor boxes size.

Comment: The `calc` package is nice but not really bullet-proof. I would stick to `\dimexpr` construct in this case. @percusse I think you should make it an answer.

Comment: @percusse: sir, you should make an answ... oh wait. `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PGF-like keys being filtered whether *the argument is a dimen or a computation or else* type of branching came later chronologically. Thus `beamer`, in a sense, predates the `pgfkeys` way of working and we should not expect much of the flexibility from `beamer` options as they are quite esoteric which might be, arguably, the reason why `pgfkeys` are developed in the first place.

In this case the key gets the argument literally and tries to give it to a dimen but the `5cm` causes TeX to stop scanning and you have the dangling `-1cm` printed. A possible solution is to make sure that the dimen computation survives via [e-TeX](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etex) extension `\dimexpr...\relax` (manual section 3.5).

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\dimpexr5cm-1cm\relax]{sidebar}
First box
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reasons `wd=5cm-1cm` fails are the following:

Internally `5cm-1cm` is directly stored in a macro `\beamer@colbox@wd`, this is then later used to set the `\hsize` to:

```
\hsize=\beamer@colbox@wd
```

At no point can either PGFmath or `calc` interact. For the latter, there needs to be a `\setlength` call, so

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\beamercolorbox\endcsname
  {\hsize=\beamer@colbox@wd}
  {\setlength\hsize{\beamer@colbox@wd}}
  {}{}
```

would do.

For this to work with PGFmath we could substitute to

```
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\beamercolorbox\endcsname
  {\hsize=\beamer@colbox@wd}
  {\pgfmathsetlength\hsize{\beamer@colbox@wd}}
  {}{}
```

replacing LaTeX’s (and `calc`’s) `\setlength` with `\pgfmathsetlength` which would make it possible to use any PGFmath option in the `wd` key.

Both of these solutions will fail for rounded boxes (`rounded=true`) because the `\beamer@colbox@wd` macro is used again which we could solve by also fixing another occurrences of either `\beamer@colbox@wd` or `\bmb@width`.

It might be easier to simply redefine the `wd` key so that it does immediately evaluate the value:

```
\define@key{beamercolbox}{wd}{\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\beamer@colbox@wd{#1}}
```

or, for `calc`, something like

```
\define@key{beamercolbox}{wd}{\setlength\pgfutil@tempdima{#1}% any "temp" is okay
                              \edef\beamer@colbox@wd{\the\pgfutil@tempdima}}
```

---

Obviously this needs to be done for other keys, too, if you want to use them; in the `beamercolbox` namespace there are also `ht`, `dp`, `leftskip` and `rightskip`. If you use those calculations often, it might be worth it (and it also might be better to ask the developers); otherwise use the already discussed `\dimexpr` solution.

Comment: Uf! I just wanted to be sure that i wasn't doing anything wrong. In any case I'll try to understand your answer and apply in future themes. Thank you.

Comment: @Ignasi You weren’t doing anything wrong. The keys from the `beamercolorbox` environment simply aren’t setup for dimension calculation. My answer shows how one would correct that (at best in the source files directly), for a one-time problem, use `\dimexpr`. :)