# Why is the width in nwu-lecture-style not working?

Tags: beamer, lengths, width

It seems that the code in `nwu-lecture-style`:

```
\insertshortauthor[width=2cm-2pt,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
```

is not working? I tried:

```
\insertshortauthor[width=2cm minus 2pt,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
```

It is not working neither, how to solve it?

Comment: Could you post a complete [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: I think [why-a-calc-operation-in-width-of-beamercolorbox-doesnt-work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140230/why-a-calc-operation-in-width-of-beamercolorbox-doesnt-work) is related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I use:

```
\newlength{\shortauthor}
\setlength{\shortauthor}{2cm minus 2pt}
\insertshortauthor[width=\shortauthor,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 \insertshortauthor[width=\dimexpr2cm-2pt,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
```