# Transparent and centered image into a frame formed for two bars (head and side)

Tags: beamer, graphics, horizontal-alignment, backgrounds

I tried to center a transparent image into a beamer slide and it worked perfectly (code is shown below), but now I have a `beamer` presentation with two bars: one on the head (2.5cm) and one on the left side (2.5cm). I want to center a figure just in the new frame formed with these two bars, could you help me with this?

Thank you very much in advance. Regards!

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[opacity=0.3, at=(current page.center)] {
   \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce the height and width of the figure by the desired amounts and perform a shift in the node placement specification:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

{
\usebackgroundtemplate{% 
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[opacity=0.3] at ([xshift=1.25cm,yshift=-1.25cm]current page.center) { \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\paperheight-2.5cm\relax,
width=\dimexpr\paperwidth-2.5cm\relax]{example-image-a}}; }

\begin{frame}
\null
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, thank you very much, Gonzalo. It worked perfectly. I just had to make some slight modifications to accomodate the figure as I wanted. (¿Puedo meter este código en el "beamertheme" que estoy haciendo? Lo probaré.)

Comment: @N0p4l1t0 You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept the answer if you consider it solved your problem; in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954). Claro que puedes usar el código en tu tema.

Comment: Answer accepted! 

Agregué el código a mi tema y sí funcionó. Por otro lado, @Gonzalo, cuando agrego los números de página a mis diapositivas, la barra lateral se "despinta" en la parte de abajo, es decir, en la parte donde está el pie de página. ¿Sabes si hay un hilo con este tema? ¿O lo puedo abrir como nuevo? (Es mi primera vez en esta página, y obviamente haré la pregunta en inglés, porque entiendo que es la "mother tongue" de esta web. Gracias. Saludos.)

Comment: @N0p4l1t0: May be this question can help you:   http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139520/how-to-add-the-footnote-in-the-right-down-corner-with-the-background-coloronly/140031#140031

Comment: It dit, @Ignasi, thank you very much! Best regards!